reinforcement learning environment that arrives at a specified area in a simple 3D space
For my research, I've been testing reinforcement learning code. What I'm trying now is to create an Environment and Reward function to arrive at the desired area (less than a certain distance from the destination, less than a certain speed) by setting two actions, speed and angle (Azimuth, Heading angle), when the starting point and destination are fixed, and test it. I've applied several RL algorithms such as SAC, DDPG, and PPO, but all of them are similarly not working well. I would appreciate if you can tell me how to improve my code or the github ref that you tried similarly.
This is my env code.
`class CombinedEnv_PAPER_VER_1:
    def __init__(self, lower_bound, upper_bound, goal, fail_penalty = -10000,
             step_penalty=-0.1, success_reward=10000, max_steps=100, approach_reward=3):
    self.lower_bound = np.array(lower_bound)
    self.upper_bound = np.array(upper_bound)
    # self.goal = T.tensor(goal, dtype=T.float32)
    self.goal = goal
    self.step_penalty = step_penalty
    self.fail_penalty = fail_penalty
    self.success_reward = success_reward
    self.max_steps = max_steps
    self.approach_reward = approach_reward
    self.current_step = 0

#def reset(self):
 #    = 0

def step(self, state, action):
    dt = 0.8
    self.current_step += 1
    done = False
    fail = False

    dtr = torch.pi/180
    rtd = 180/torch.pi
    
    
    
    self.state = state.squeeze()
    # state_new = torch.zero(1,5)
    state_new = self.state.clone().detach()
    state_new[0] += 1

    Time_step = self.state[0].unsqueeze(0)
    Position = self.state[1:3]
    Velocity = self.state[3]
    Angle = self.state[4]
    Z = self.state[5]
    Theta = self.state[6]
    
    
    
    V_ang = action[0,0]
    A_ang = action[0,1]
    Theta_ang = action[0,2]
    
    
    
    Velocity_new = Velocity + V_ang
    
    if Velocity_new >= 22.36 or Velocity_new <= 0:
        Reward_V_XY_out = -0.1
    else:
        Reward_V_XY_out = 0
            
    Velocity_new = torch.clamp(Velocity_new, min=0, max=22.36)
      
    
    Angle_new = (Angle + A_ang)%360
    Theta_new = (Theta + Theta_ang)%360
    
    if Theta_new >= 26.6 or Theta_new <= 0:
        Reward_Theta_out = -0.1
    else:
        Reward_Theta_out = 0
    
    Theta_new = torch.clamp(Theta_new, min=0, max=26.6)
    
    
   
    Reward_out = Reward_V_XY_out + Reward_Theta_out
    
    
   
    
    Angle_pos = 0.5*(Angle_new+Angle)*dtr
    Theta_pos = 0.5*(Theta_new+Theta)*dtr
    Vel_pos = 0.5*(Velocity+Velocity_new)
    
    
    Pos_X = Vel_pos*dt*torch.cos(Theta_pos)*torch.cos(Angle_pos)
    Pos_Y = Vel_pos*dt*torch.cos(Theta_pos)*torch.sin(Angle_pos)
    Pos_Z = - Vel_pos*dt*torch.sin(Theta_pos)
    

    Position_X = self.state[1] + Pos_X
    Position_Y = self.state[2] + Pos_Y
    Position_Z = self.state[5] + Pos_Z
    
    Position_old = torch.tensor([self.state[1],self.state[2],self.state[5]])
    Position_new = torch.tensor([Position_X,Position_Y,Position_Z])
    Position_XY = torch.tensor([Position_X,Position_Y])
     
   
    state_new[1] = Position_X
    state_new[2] = Position_Y
    state_new[3] = Velocity_new
    state_new[4] = Angle_new
    state_new[5] = Position_Z
    state_new[6] = Theta_new

    next_state = state_new.unsqueeze(0)

    
    
    lower_bound_xy = np.array(torch.tensor([self.lower_bound[0],self.lower_bound[1]]))
    upper_bound_xy = np.array(torch.tensor([self.upper_bound[0],self.upper_bound[1]]))  
    
    out_of_bounds = np.logical_or(Position_XY.numpy() < lower_bound_xy, Position_XY.numpy() > upper_bound_xy)
    out_of_Z = Position_Z < 0
    
    Axis_high = torch.FloatTensor([self.upper_bound[0],self.upper_bound[1],self.upper_bound[2]])
    Axis_low = torch.FloatTensor([self.lower_bound[0],self.lower_bound[1],self.lower_bound[2]])
    
    Axis = torch.norm(Axis_high-Axis_low,p=2)
    
    goal_pos_tot = torch.tensor([self.goal[0], self.goal[1], self.goal[2]])
    goal_pos_xy = torch.tensor([self.goal[0], self.goal[1]])
    
    
    Distance_old= torch.norm(Position_old - goal_pos_tot, p=2)
    Distance_new = torch.norm(Position_new - goal_pos_tot, p=2)
    
    # Reward_Dist = (Distance_old-Distance_new)/Distance_old
    D = Distance_new/Axis
    V = Velocity_new/2
    
    Reward_sum = -(torch.exp(-((D-1)**2 + V**2)) + torch.exp(-(D**2 + (V-1)**2))) - 0.3*V - 0.1*D

    
   
    # Reward_sum = Reward_Dist + Reward_out
    

    if np.any(out_of_bounds) or out_of_Z:
        reward = torch.tensor([self.fail_penalty]).unsqueeze(1) + Reward_sum + self.step_penalty
        fail = True
        done = True
    elif Distance_new < 15 and Velocity_new <= 5:
        reward = self.step_penalty +  Reward_sum + torch.tensor([self.success_reward]).unsqueeze(1)

        done = True
    else:
        Reward_bonus = 0
        if Distance_new > Axis/2:
            
            Reward_bonus += -(22.36-Velocity_new)/22.36 
        else:
            Reward_bonus += (22.36-Velocity_new)/22.36   
            
            
        reward = self.step_penalty + Reward_sum


    reward = reward.clone().detach()
    return next_state, reward, done, fail  `

